# Dynamically created iframe not working on Safari

Tags: jquery, iframe, safari

I have a weird problem and I find no answer on google... I dynamically create and fullfil an iframe with jquery on a page. It works fine withFF and IE, but **not with Safari**.

The iframe is created but empty (the message "greetings from the iframe !" is missing).
Here is a piece of code to illustrate it :

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="fr-fr" lang="fr-fr" >
 <head>
  <title>iframe</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {

    var jFrame = $('<iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe">');
    jFrame.css({'height':'40px','width':'200px'}).appendTo($('#container'));

    $('#myiframe').load(function() {
     jFrame.contents().find("body").html('greetings from the iframe !');
    });

   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I really wonder why the iframe stays empty with Safari. It seems like if "contents()" was not well interpreted...

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure to attach the `load` event handler before it can possibly fire, like this:

```
$('<iframe id="myiframe" name="myiframe" />')
  .css({'height':'40px','width':'200px'})
  .load(function() {
     $(this).contents().find("body").html('greetings from the iframe !');
  })
  .appendTo('#container');
```

That being said, I'm not positive the `load` event is *required* to fire if there was no actual load (your frame has no `src`), all browsers may be following the spec here, yet still be inconsistent.  But...Safari has always been a little "off" with `load` and `ready` events, so using the approach above will help that as much as possible.  One last note, [`.appendTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) can take a selector directly ;)

Comment: Dear Nick,

Thank you for your answer, it works fine !

I'm quite newbie with jQuery and I honnestly don't understand why my piece of code does not work like yours. Is it something about synchro/asynchro ?

Thank you once again,
mhammout

Comment: @mhammout - The issue is that the `load` event fires *immediately* when you inserted it into the DOM, before your `.load(...)` even had a chance to run, so even though it rigged up a handler to run when that event happens, the event *already* happened, make sense?